# wp_delete_attachment, wp_delete_file_from_directory and wp_delete_file() does not delete file from server

Tags: php, wordpress, delete-file

I am trying to regenerate a PDF file whenever a post is being saved/updated. The PDF file name changes according to post_meta data, therefore I want to delete the existing PDF attachment AND the file from the server when a post is saved/updated, before the pdf gets regenerated and attached.

wp_delete_attachment() deletes the attachment alright, but the file stays on the server even when forced to delete.

I also tried wp_delete_file_from_directory( $file, $path); It returns true for having deleted the file, but the file stays on the server. Same for wp_delete_file();

The only thing that seemed to be working was unlink(), but that creates another problem, because in case the file name doesn't change, unlink() seems to put a stop to creating the file with the same name.

```
       wp_update_post( $my_post );

            if(get_post_status( $post_id ) == "publish"):

                    $existing_PDFs = get_attached_media('application/pdf', $post_id);

                    foreach($existing_PDFs as $pdf):

                       $file = get_attached_file($pdf->ID, true);
                       $path = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

                       wp_delete_file_from_directory( $file, $path);

                       wp_delete_file( $file );

                       wp_delete_attachment($pdf->ID, true);


                    endforeach;

                    include('generate-single-machine-pdf.php');
            endif;
```

What's the secret to get Wordpress to delete a file from the server along with the attachment?

Comment: @unlink() see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to conditionally use unlink after wp_delete_attachment in case the generated PDF had the same name as the deleted PDF. In that case no deletion of attachment or unlinking was needed, only to overwrite the existing file.

For updating posts:

```
$savePath = trailingslashit($uploads_dir).$new_file_name.'.pdf';

$pdf->Output($savePath, 'F');

$existing_PDF = get_attached_media('application/pdf', $post_id);

foreach($existing_PDF as $pdf):

    $oldPDFID= $pdf->ID;

    $file = get_attached_file($oldPDFID, true);

    $old_file_name = pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_BASENAME);

endforeach;

}

$old_pdf = pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_BASENAME);

#######CREATE PDF ATTACHMENT####
$args = array(
    'post_title' => "$new_file_name",
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_mime_type' => 'application/pdf',
);
$new_file_name = $new_file_name.".pdf";

//DELETE OLD ATTACHMENT
if($new_file_name != $old_file_name):
    wp_delete_attachment($oldPDFID, true);
    unlink($file);
endif;

$pdfID = wp_insert_attachment($args, $savePath, $post_id);
```